# Fire java method from another class onclick in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to call a java method from another class in this jsp. The method have to take in the input value.
I do not want the page to refresh because the input value will be gone.
I've tried using request.setAttribute but it refreshes the page.
Is it possible to use AJAX or Javascript to get the input value without refreshing the page?

```
<input type="file" id="exampleInputFile1" name="inputFile1">
```

//The method needs to get the value of the input

```
<%
String input = "lala";
createDog(String input);
%>
```

Comment: The code hasn't an input value, how would you like to get it in JSP?

Comment: i would like to know how i can call this method in the JSP... I've already added the a String to pass it into the method.

Comment: You can't until you get the value of input string, either you do it on server or in browser that you should clarify.

Comment: i've updated it. but i don't know how to call the method in jsp